# How to show payment method in admin only ? (Magento 1)

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

What is the best way to enable a Payment Method only in backend part in Magento 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generic configuration based way of doing this in core Magento (some payment methods may manually implement this kind of option).

If you wish to write an extension for doing this, your best bet will likely be to write an event observer for the event `payment_method_is_active` in the adminhtml namespace. In this event you can check the `getCode` method of the payment method and check if it's in a list of either hard-coded or configured payment methods, then modify the result object.

There are some extensions floating around that do this, such as `GetCommerce_AdminPayments`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free extension on `GitHub` you can download it. [Module Link](https://github.com/GetCommerce/Magento-Admin-Payments)

**Summery of above extension:**

> listen event for `adminhtml` at config.xml

```
<events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
       <observers>
         <getcommerce_admin_payments>
         <type>model</type>                    
         <class>GetCommerce_AdminPayments_Model_Observer</class>
         <method>enablePaymentMethods</method>
         </getcommerce_admin_payments>
        </observers>
     </payment_method_is_active>
</events>
```

In observer you can set payment method `False`

Hope Above will help!